# Finding Changed Form Element With jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a form(id="search_options") and i tracking changes in form by:

```
    $("#search_options").change(function() { 
        // Bla Bla Bla
    });
```

In this form i have many inputs and one of is select(id="project_category") and i want to catch if user changed project_category select or another input. How can i done this ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plugin made for exactly this purpose:

**[jQuery Form Observe](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-form-observe/)**

> This plugin observes values of form
>   elements. When end-user changes any
>   values of input elements, observer
>   shows which values were changed. And
>   observer also alerts to users when
>   they try to move out from the page
>   before submitting changes.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking to do could be accomplished 2 ways I can think of off the top of my head.
First, Capture the change event for all input items in your form individually

```
$("#search_options input,#search_options select").change(function() { 
   // "this" is the input that has changed so you would check if it had id = "project_category" here        
});
```

Alternatively you could track the current value of the "project_category" on every change

```
var current_Project_Category = ""; 
$("#search_options").change(function() { 
        if(current_Project_Category != $(this).find("#project_category").val())
        { 
           //project category has changed so mark this as the current one 
           //also run any change code here
           current_Project_Category = $(this).find("#project_category").val()   
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
$("#search_options").find('input,select').change(function() {
    var changedId = $(this).attr('id');
    var newVal = $(this).val();
});
```